# Typescript - module functions reference in different file - "could not find symbol"

Tags: javascript, typescript, web-essentials

Apologies if the answer to this is simple, or I've mis-read the typescript documentation, but..

I have a module:

```
module Utils{

    export function MyFunction(str: string):string {
        return // something to do with string
    }

}
```

I want to use this in another .ts file (Clients.ts) so at the top I add a reference and try to use it:

```
/// <reference path="Utils.ts" />
Utils.MyFunction(str);
```

But get the following error:

```
/*

Compile Error. 
See error list for details
 [path]/Clients.ts(26,39): error TS2095: Could not find symbol 'Utils'.
 [path]/Clients.ts(30,49): error TS2095: Could not find symbol 'Utils'.
error TS5037: Cannot compile external modules unless the '--module' flag is provided.


*/
```

Could anybody explain what I'm doing wrong?

Using VS2012, with Web Essentials and TypeScript 0.9.1

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the answer myself. What I was actually looking for was a static method on a class. As per the below:

```
class Utils {

    static MyFunction(str: string): string {
        return //... do something with string
    }
}
```

And this worked in the Client.ts

```
/// <reference path="Utils.ts" />
var x = Utils.MyFunction(str);
```

Answer (score 2):

The error you are getting `error TS5037: Cannot compile external modules unless the '--module' flag is provided.` is not something you would get with your code.

You would get this only if you export something at the root level of your file. e.g.

```
export module Utils{ // Notice the export keyword 

    export function MyFunction(str: string):string {
        return // something to do with string
    }

}
```

In this case you are using an external module loader and typescript needs to know if its `amd`(requirejs/browser) or `commonjs`(node/server side)

PS: I did a video on the subject : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDrWLMUY0R0&hd=1

Comment: This wasn't my problem. Will post an answer below.